# change all dates but not the time in mysql using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a lot of rows, which are in a mysql db table, and they are in datetime format. Is there a way that i could change the year of the dates without changing their time?

Ex.

- 2000-05-01 11:00:00
- 2000-01-01 06:30:00
- 2000-01-01 07:00:00

changing them to

- 2050-05-01 11:00:00
- 2050-01-01 06:30:00
- 2050-01-01 07:00:00

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to add them by 50 years,

```
UPDATE tableName
SET columnName = columnName + INTERVAL 50 YEAR
```

- [MySQL DATE_ADD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also:-

```
UPDATE table_name SET columnName = concat('2011-01-12 ', time(columnName))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or You can use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function

```
UPDATE tableName
SET field = DATE_FORMAT(field, '2050-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

In this case you change all years to same date. You can set similar months, days or time part.

Comment: The `'%T '` format returns hours minutes and seconds ("hh:mm:ss"). The `':%i:%s'` in the format string is unneeded.